# Using pointer to character as the argument of strtok

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, strtok

I try to split the string by using `strtok` function. But the program become failed if i use the pointer to character as the argument of this function.

If i initialize the string as `s2` or `s3` the program works well. But if i use pointer to character as `s1` the program get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

```
char *s1 = "1A 2B 3C 4D";
char s2[] = "1A 2B 3C 4D";
char s3[20] = "1A 2B 3C 4D";
```

The problem is the other functions, `printf` and `strlen` work without failure, but only `strtok` get error.

The complete code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void split_string(char *s) {
    char * token = strtok(s," ");
    while (token != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}

int main()
{
    char *s1 = "1A 2B 3C 4D";
    char s2[] = "1A 2B 3C 4D";
    char s3[20] = "1A 2B 3C 4D";
    printf("size of s1 = %ld, s2 = %ld, s3 = %ld\n", strlen(s1), strlen(s2), strlen(s3));
    printf("s1: %s\ns2: %s\ns3: %s\n",s1,s2,s3);
    printf("split s2: \n");
    split_string(s2);
    printf("split s3: \n");
    split_string(s3);
    printf("split s1: \n");
    split_string(s1);
    return 0;
}
```

The result after running:

```
size of s1 = 11, s2 = 11, s3 = 11
s1: 1A 2B 3C 4D
s2: 1A 2B 3C 4D
s3: 1A 2B 3C 4D
split s2: 
1A
2B
3C
4D
split s3: 
1A
2B
3C
4D
split s1: 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

`strtok` from `man` page: `char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);`

Please help to understand this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Battousai*, firstly you need to use your reverse side of the katana to achieve your aim by using readable/writable area. If you don't do this, unless the compiler/OS(*Kamiya Kaoru*) doesn't prevent you, 
*Shishio Makoto* may ruin guys important for you and around you via *Sojiro Seta*, living in your memory such as *Sanosuke Sagara*, *Yahiko Myojin*.

> `strtok` writes into the string you give it - overwriting the
>   separator character with null and keeping a pointer to the rest of the
>   string.

```
char *s1 = "1A 2B 3C 4D"; // you have a pointer to some read-only characters
char s2[] = "1A 2B 3C 4D"; // same, decay into pointer
char s3[20] = "1A 2B 3C 4D"; // a twenty element array of characters that you can do what you like with.
```

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` modifies the data given to it and character literals are read only. It will cause problems, in this case a segfault.

The other forms will cause a copy of the read only data to be made so they work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`s1` points to a string literal, which is constant, any attepmpt to modify a string literal will result in a segfault.

Comment: s1 is pointer that points to string literal. It's not a string literal, no ?

Comment: @Hitokiri, yes, that is correct, I clarified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `strtok()` modifies the string pointed to by its argument - (it does not parse it only) and by giving `s1` as argument you attempt to modify a string literal.

---

In your case:

```
char s2[] = "1A 2B 3C 4D";
char s3[20] = "1A 2B 3C 4D";
```

`s2` and `s3` are both modifiable `char` arrays which each hold a string, whereas:

```
char *s1 = "1A 2B 3C 4D";
```

`s1` is a pointer to the string literal `"1A 2B 3C 4D"`, which is read-only and can´t be modified.

Any attempt to modify a string literal causes undefined behavior and in your case the segmentation fault in memory.

From ISO:IEC 9899:2018  (C18) Section 6.4.5/7 - "String literals":

> *"It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**"*

Comment: s2 modifiable? s2[15] = 'X' possible?

Comment: @snr Yes, `s2` is modifiable, f.e. `s2[0] = 'X';` is possible. I didn´t say it is permissible to write beyond the bounds of the array though.